# Не срабатывают специальные возможности на точках (point)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет.
Есть игровое поле (как в настолках с кубиком). На поле расположены точки (empty object). Точки последовательны и некоторые из них имеют специальные возможности, например: бонус (прибавляет к броску кубика некоторое количество шагов), штраф, пропуск хода и т.д. Создал два скрипта, игрока и точки. При попадании на точку условие не срабатывает. Опыта нет, поэтому сказать что я пробовал не могу. Стекло протирал, по колесам стучал. Мануалы меня запутывали ещё больше: Сделайте через Rigidbody, через Collider, через теги, через слои. Короче, не выходит каменный цветок. Должно быть решение проще. Вот кусок кода:

```
void ProcessPoint(Player player, BonusPoint point)
    {
        if (point.bonus != 0)
        {
            player.currentPoint += point.bonus;
            if (player.currentPoint >= points.Length - 1) 
                player.currentPoint = points.Length - 1; 
            StartCoroutine(MoveTo(player, points[player.currentPoint].position));
        }
    }       
    
    IEnumerator MoveTo(Player player, Vector3 target)
    {
        while (Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position, target) > 0.01f)
        {
            player.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(player.transform.position, target, speed * Time.deltaTime);
            yield return null;
        }

        player.transform.position = target;
        BonusPoint point = points[player.currentPoint].GetComponent<BonusPoint>();
        if (point != null) ProcessPoint(player, point);
    }
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, люди добрые.